# fixed text inside TextField SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, textfield

i want to put some fixed text inside TextField like "email: ....."

I tryed this:

```
HStack {
    Image(systemName: "list.bullet").foregroundColor(.gray)
    Text("email:")
    TextField("", text: Binding(
        get: { viewModel.email },
        set: { viewModel.email = $0 }
    ))
        .textFieldStyle(DefaultTextFieldStyle())
        .frame(width: 60)
}
.padding()
.overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(
viewModel.emailValid() ? Color.gray : Color.red, lineWidth: 1
))
```

The problem is that this implementation only allows to click in specific part (inside the textField space) but i want to make all clickable to be more friendly to edit.

I tryed putting TextField and Text inside ZStack but the text entered by the user in inside te "Email text".

Maybe its possible to move the textField cursor to the end of the "email" text, or another implementation?
Thanks!

Comment: are you looking for this? `TextField("", text: $input, prompt: Text("email"))`

Comment: i want that the text inside TextField isn´t deleted when writing

Answer (score 0):

So if its mainly about activating the TextField on tap/click on any area of the element, you can use programmatic focus for `TextField`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var input = ""
    @FocusState var focused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "list.bullet").foregroundColor(.gray)
            Text("email:")
            TextField("", text: $input)
                .frame(width: 80)
                .focused($focused)
        }
        .padding()
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(
        true ? Color.gray : Color.red, lineWidth: 1
        ))
        
        .contentShape(Rectangle()) // makes the whole element tappable
        .onTapGesture {
            focused = true // sets focus for textField
        }
    }
}
```